# What am I getting wrong in this IF syntax?

Tags: windows, batch-file, printing, windows-10, network-printers

We have being installing some new computers on my company and these new computers came with Windows 10 and, before that, we were using Windows 7. The first problem we had was the way Windows 10 manages the printers, not selecting a default one. I was able to turn it off through a batch file that executes everytime someone logs in, altering the registry.

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows" /v LegacyDefaultPrinterMode /t "REG_DWORD" /d "1" /f
```

The thing after that is, when the printer management was turned off, Windows assinged any of the printers as a default, so i edited the batch file to set the local printer connected to USB001 as the default.

```
wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
```

However, some computer use a remote printer, connected as a local port, using the name of the remote computer as "\\ComputerName\SamsungM" (The name of the computer may change, but all the printers end with "SamsungM" ).
I tried, then, to modify the batch once again. Now it has to assign the USB001 printer as default, if one is connected and, if not, assign as default the one where the portname finishes as "samsungm", but the batch is not working...

```
set var=wmic printer get portname
%var% > portas.txt
if /I "%samsungm" == "portas.txt" equal (
wmic printer where "PortName like '%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
) else (
wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

The individual commands to set the default printer are working, what led me to thinking it must be the If syntax that I'm getting wrong. Can someone help me?

EDIT1: After some help on the comments, I realized a few errors...
Maybe this look a little more to what I want it to do:

```
C:\set var=wmic printer get portname
C:\%var%
PortName
\\ses267827\samsungm
usb001
C:\%var% > ports.txt
C:\findstr /E /I ".samsungm" ports.txt
C:\if ERRORLEVEL 0 (wmic printer where "PortName like '%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter) else (wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter)
```

But it still not works...

EDIT2: I have just realized it's backwards.
It should be

```
C:\set var=wmic printer get portname
C:\%var%
PortName
\\ses267827\samsungm
usb001
C:\%var% > ports.txt
C:\findstr /E /I "usb001" ports.txt
C:\if ERRORLEVEL 0 (wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter) else (wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter)
```

I'll test it in a few minutes.

EDIT3: Tests done. Worked for the USB printer, but not for the SamsungM. It seems like the `ERRORLEVEL` is not changing when `findstr` doesn't find `usb001` in the ports.txt file.

Comment: What's `%samsungm`? A variable with a typo or a literal string?. What's `equal` supposed to do? Type `if /?` and compare `if` syntax with yours.

Comment: samsungm is a string. I was just reading the ```/?``` and saw that it's supposed to be .samsungm, right? The equal is supposed to look for equality between the ".samsungm" and the content inside the file "portas.txt"...

Comment: also, why are you comparing the string or variable `%samsungm` with `portas.txt`.. Did you expect the if statement to read the file content?

Comment: What do you guess, `==` is doing?

Comment: nevermind, you already said it. The if statement does not know that `portas.txt` is a file you want it to read, even if it did, it cannot read files. You need to actually tell the batch file to read from the file and not use `portas.txt` as a literal string.

Comment: Nope :). So please so what your expected ouput from `wmic printer get portname` looks like so I can see what you need to do. Then we can show you the correct way.

Comment: @Stephan I'm not sure about the ```==```. It replaces the necessity of ```equal```?

Comment: ```wmic printer get portname``` returns:
PortName
\\ses267827\samsungm
USB001
Each of them in a separate line

Comment: There is no necessity for `equal` at all. I think you misread the help.

Comment: If you did really read the help for the `IF` command you would have definitely seen this: `string1==string2  Specifies a true condition if the specified text string match.` The usage syntax is quite literal. `IF [NOT] string1==string2 command`

Comment: anyway, I suggest you use a `for` loop and utilize `findstr` to find the string instead of piping to file. If you want actual help with an answer with this, I suggest you edit the question and show an actual example of your output from `wmic printer get portname /value` so I can use your output as example.

Comment: Maybe i should use ```findstr```, then? I tried it a while and analyzing the ```%ERRORLEVEL%```, but couldn't make it work either.

Comment: Ok, @GerhardBarnard. Will do!

Comment: try `... like '%%samsungm'" ...` (the batch file parser requires the `%` to be doubled to act as a character instead of the beginning of a variable)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a temporary file. You can filter the output of the command directly:

```
wmic printer get portname | findstr /xi "USB001" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% == 0 (
  wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
) else (
  wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

or [a bit shorter](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```
wmic printer get portname | findstr /xi "USB001" >nul 2>&1 && (
  wmic printer where portname="USB001" call setdefaultprinter
) || (      
  wmic printer where "PortName like '%%samsungm'" call setdefaultprinter
)
```

`>nul 2>&1` redirects all output of the `wmic` command to the NUL device. We don't need the output, just the errorlevel.

The main issue with your last try was the percent sign (used by `wmic` as a wildcard). The Batch file parser just deletes it, because it thinks it's the start of a variable and it can't find the second one to mark the end of the variable name. To use a literal `%`, you have to double it (it's called "escaping")  (just within a batch file; you don't have to do it directly on the command line)

Comment: Yours worked when there is a printer connected via USB001, but it didn't make the right printer default when there was nothing connected on the USB. It returned "No Instance(s) Available".

Comment: Your question states "if there is a `*samsungm`, then make that the default printer,else make the `USB001` printer the default printer. When there is no `USB001`, how to find "the right printer"?

Comment: Oh, god. It's backwards. It should say "if there is a ```USB001```, then make that the default printer, else make the ```*samsungm``` the default printer. I'll edit the original post.

Comment: adapted my answer (easy, as the logic stays the same)

Comment: The same thing still happens. Works for one of the printer, but not for the other one.